# Problems following a tutorial on how to code a Soundboard in Android Studio, due to new releases with new code

Tags: android

**I am new**, and I have almost 0 experience with Android Studio, so **I need somebody who uses simple words, to help me understand better**.

I have some problems following the second episode of the video-tutorials on YouTube by RedCode Development to code a Soundboard in Android Studio.

[If you click here, you can see](https://youtu.be/6xuq_Z16STk?list=PLj2QEgPXNW-TLqpCHFXPQ77s8PDmFTRZq&t=582) that he (the author of the video-tutorial) writes the following code:

```
    android:id="@id/soundboard_toolbar"/>
```

> **Edit**: the line code above is wrong, write this one to make it right:

```
    android:id="@+id/soundboard_toolbar"/>
```

[That's the 1st error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t577v.png) (*@id/soundboard_toolbar* is marked as an *error* in red in my Editor) and I thought that the problem was going to be solved defining *soundboard_toolbar*, or writing additional code.

Then, [we go to minute 11:15](https://youtu.be/6xuq_Z16STk?list=PLj2QEgPXNW-TLqpCHFXPQ77s8PDmFTRZq&t=615) and we can see he writes the code:

```
toolbar Toolbar;
```

> **Edit**: the line code above is wrong, write this one to make it right:

```
Toolbar toolbar;
```

Followed by the code:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.soundboard_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Wherever [*toolbar* is written, it gives me an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XLUv.png).

If you look at the comments [you can see there is somebody with a similar problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaj7g.png).

How to solve the errors?

Comment: Hey Apeiros, welcome to SO. Please make sure you have one question per post, or it becomes very hard to keep track of answers. There's two distinct errors here you mention and they're unrelated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should maybe post one question per time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!

When [the author of the tutorial enters the line code: "*Toolbar toolbar;*"](https://youtu.be/6xuq_Z16STk?list=PLj2QEgPXNW-TLqpCHFXPQ77s8PDmFTRZq&t=612) I selected the option "***Toolbar (androidx.appcompat.widget)***" to make it work.

Then he proceeds to write the line code: "*toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.soundboard_toolbar);*" and the trick is, [when writing *Toolbar* inside the brackets](https://youtu.be/6xuq_Z16STk?list=PLj2QEgPXNW-TLqpCHFXPQ77s8PDmFTRZq&t=627), to select the same option of before, which is ***Toolbar (androidx.appcompat.widget)***.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The first error is indeed as you were suspecting: you have not defined `@id/soundboard_toolbar`. You need to change it to `@+id/soundboard_toolbar` for it to work, as the author of the video you link does. You can find a detailed explanation on how this works on the [Android Developers website](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#id) and on other answers here on StackOverflow.

The second error is hard to troubleshoot without you posting what the actual error is. I suspect it is because you're once again not following along the tutorial. The tutorial author writes:

```java
Toolbar toolbar;
```

but you wrote:

```java
toolbar Toolbar;
```

The two things are entirely different, in Java; the first word is the type, and the second the name of the field you're declaring. Since there is no `toolbar` type, you get an error for that.

Please make sure you follow the tutorial instructions to the dot: Java code is case sensitive, and even a single mistyped or missed character can completely change the meaning of what you write for the IDE.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made too many errors. I didn't see the "+" at the id, and the Toolbar part, well I did as said in the tutorial, but when writing it here by hand, I wrote it wrong :|

Comment: What do I do if the problem persists?

Comment: Hey @rock3r! Thanks to you, for your precious help and kind words, and to repeating the project, the problem is now solved! I also suggest you that when you give advice on making one question per post, you explain in detail why, some persons could get angry, not understanding why you demand that, and/or not understanding if it's right or not. For me, it was a relief to read your answer in a short time. So, thank you, twice! :)

Comment: @ApeirosPerfection it's the StackOverflow etiquette — makes it easy to provide answers (someone may be able to answer one question but not others) and it's the only way an answer can be marked as accepted. Speaking of which: please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue :)